# How to pass parameter to advanced rest client service

Tags: parameter-passing, advanced-rest-client

I am rest web-service which take single parameter. I am using advanced rest client  to test but getting missing parameter error; I am call and passing parameter as following;

https://agentwebservices.ac.uk/Rest/Modules/13327/Screens/U_LookUps/Data/StudentByCode?PeopeCode="33724"

I have string 337724 and '337724' but same error

so the method is StudentByCode(string PeopeCode)

Comment: is there anyone know how to do that

Comment: I am struggling on this small thing I am not sure what possible I am doing wrong

Comment: need help here!